# Module installed but can't find a shared library installed by Brew

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, barcode-scanner

I need to install a module pyzbar which depends on another called zbar. According to the pypi [link](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) I first need to install zbar via

```
brew install zbar
```

then install the pyzbar

```
pip install pyzbar
```

Having done of that when trying to run a code based on importing specific part of the module, it gives an error.

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
```

The error is
ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library

How to check where exactly is the issue coming from and how to resolve it?

Here are steps I took after checking comments:
1- Tried finding libzbar file and some how link that to the path so that the pyzbar file zbar_library.py can find that. The libzbar files were in this location /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zbar/0.23.90 installed by homebrew and not in usr/local/lib (which surprisingly no such directory exists on my mac). The way I added the location of zbar lib file to path was by

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```

in the terminal while I'm in the conda environment on which my python is running. Now when trying to run python while importing pyzbar it finds something and no longer give the "no shared lib found" error, but gives the following errors:

```
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/zbar_library.py", line 66, in load
    libzbar = cdll.LoadLibrary(path)
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/libzbar.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/lib/libzbar.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zbar/0.23.90/lib/libzbar.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/lib/libzbar.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zbar/0.23.90/lib/libzbar.0.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: I guess no if that happens than error may rectify differently are you sure that you are downloading package to same environment and using that environment currently

Comment: Homebrew should link the library in /usr/local/lib. If it’s there (look for a file called libzbar.so or similar), then maybe your library search path doesn’t include /usr/local/lib.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the directory usr/local/lib does not even exist on my mac. I checked and the closest thing to libzbar I found were libzbar.dylib and libzbar.a which were in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zbar/0.23.90/lib. So I added that to the path and yet I still get the error "Unable to find zbar shared library". This is what is causing this "path = find_library('zbar')" apparently unable to find zbar while my path includes the mentioned directories above.

Comment: Try `brew link zbar`. If that fails, you might need to create a `/usr/local` directory and change its ownership to your user so that you don’t need to mess with `sudo` and so on. Homebrew  usually creates that directory in that way, not sure why you wouldn’t have it.

Comment: “So I added that to the path” Which path? How did you add it? I suggest you add that information to your question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried `brew link zbar` and I got `Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/zbar/0.23.90`. I have added that to the path still same error. I explained how I added that to the path in the question in latest edit above.

Comment: I've just learned that Homebrew installed in `/opt/homebrew/` rather than `/usr/local/` for the new Apple Silicon machines. Is that what you have? Anyway, for macOS, the path used to search for shared libraries is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not `PATH` (which is the search path for executables).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes I do have the new Apple Silicon mac. I added the `/opt/homebrew/` to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and it no longer gives no shared library error but a different one as wrong architecture (just added to the question above).

Comment: So you have a mix of Intel and Apple Silicon binaries that will not work together... Did you install Python through Homebrew, or in some other way? `file /opt/homebrew/lib/libzbar.dylib` should tell you if this library is Intel (x86_64) or Apple Silicon (arm64). Because it's installed through Homebrew, I assume it'll say arm64. The Python binary should be the same, also arm64. I am guessing it's not. If so, you need to upgrade Python, or uninstall it and then install it through Homebrew.

Comment: Oh, I see now that you're using Miniconda and have Python 3.7. I would be surprised if such an old version of Python were rebuilt for arm64, so there is probably your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may have multiple python/pip versions that caused such issue. To be sure about this, you can try

```
python3.9 -m pip install pyzbar

python3.9
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
```

If there are still any errors on import, please include a list of all installed pip packages by doing

```
pip freeze --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your operating system has two versions of python even if you have configured the path correctly your system installs the library in the default python and not in the version you want.

The default directory after installing python depends on your system.

You can install directly specifying which version will receive the library:

python3.9 -m pip install "package"
python3.7 -m pip install "package"
python2.7 -m pip install "package"

It is always recommended to use a version manager , virtual environment that separates the versions and can be used individually

[reference install package](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)